# Replace each instance of a string with a variable that contains the instance index

Tags: javascript

Assume I have a large string that contains raw svg xml, and I want to change each instance of `<path` to `<path class="pathX"` (where X is the index of the matched item). What's the best way to do this in javascript? I'm using this code, which works, but I'm curious if there's a better way:

```
var svgArray = mySvgStr.split('<path ');
for(var i = 1, len = svgArray.length; i < len; i++) {
  var newStr = 'class="path' + i + '" ' + svgArray[i];
  svgArray[i] = newStr;
}
var svgWithClasses = svgArray.join('<path ');
```

Comment: You can use `XmlDOM` to parse and add the `attribute`

Comment: @stackErr is correct - don't parse the string - use an XML parser and modify things that way. You should be able to stringify the document once done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `XmlDOM` and `XPath`:

```
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); \\Create new XML Doc
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(mySvgStr); \\Load your XML into the Doc


    var pathNodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("path");
    var count = 1;
    for(count; count < pathNodes.length + 1; count++){
        pathNodes[count-1].setAttribute("class", "path" + count);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

What about parsing the XML string and using a DOM representation instead? With jQuery:

```
doc = $.parseXML(xmlString);
```

Without jQuery:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString);
```

Then you can do stuff like this:

```
var paths = doc.getElementsByTagName('path');
// add attributes here
```

This is a much less error prone approach.

Answer (score 0):

Bill F's solution is great, in fact it protects against literal strings, etc, but if you want to keep it simple without XML conversions, you could:

```
var i = 0;
a = mySvgStr.replace(/<path /g, function (match) {
    return '<path class="path"' + i;
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the occurances in the string and use a function to supply the values to replace with:

```
var i = 1;
mySvgStr = mySvgStr.replace(/<path/g, function(){
  return '<path class="path' + (i++) + '"';
});
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.